# Is logistic regression suited to predict whether or not a flight will be late 15 minutes of more? How arrange data?

Tags: logistic-regression

I have data for of past flights with quite a lot of features. I am trying to think whether a logistic regression would be suitable to predict which type of flights are likely to be late in the future. 15 or more minutes.

Since I only need to find out whether or not they are likely to be late (binary outcome, yes or no), then I figured that a logistic regression model could be suited to this problem.

However the past data is not binary, I have lateness (in minutes). Is that alright? Can I still build the model?

P.S. I haven't yet built the model, I'm currently in the planning stage and was wondering whether or not it's worth doing!

Comment: LR can work here. You can transform lateness in minute into a new target : "is it later than 15 minutes?" Yes or No. You also have to do EDA, check and maybee do features reduction. Then trying different models can be interesting.

Comment: @Malo Yeah that's a good idea! Thanks!